# Failed to install application Xamarin.Forms iOS USB

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

**After update Visual Studio to 16.9.5, i cant run all my projects on iOS with USB.**

**Outpud of Visual Studio:**

> Unhandled Exception: Xamarin.iOS.Windows.WindowsiOSException: Failed
> to install app: ApplicationVerificationFailed (3891236905) - Failed to
> verify code signature of
> /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.bW5OAX/
> extracted / Payload / EmptyIOS.iOS.app: 0xe8008019 (The application
> does not have a valid signature.)  at
> Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Installer.ApplicationSession.OnInstallProgressReport
> (IntPtr command, IntPtr status, IntPtr userData) at C: \ A \ 1 \ 1 \ s
> \ src \ Tools \ Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Launcher \ Installer 
> ApplicationSession. cs: line 324  An error occurred while trying to
> deploy the “EmptyIOS.iOS.app” application. Details: Error running
> hotrestart: ‘An unexpected error occurred and the process has been
> terminated’. Command: ‘deploy -u = 00008020-000A4C6A2188003A -i =
> com.companyname.EmptyIOS -n = EmptyIOS.iOS.app’  3> Deployment failed.
> Failed to deploy application “EmptyIOS.iOS.app” on “iPhone (Andrew)”.
> See the logs for more information.  ========== Build: success: 2, with
> errors: 0, no changes: 0, skipped: 0 ==========  ==========
> Deployment: successful: 0, with errors: 1, skipped: 0 ==========

**iOS Bundle Signing:**

> “Automatic provisioning failed, please check the logs”

**Logs of Visual:**

> Xamarin.VisualStudio.Progress.ProgressReportService|Information|0|Resolving certificate...
> Xamarin.VisualStudio.Progress.ProgressReportService|Information|0|Saving Apple Development certificates...
> Xamarin.VisualStudio.Progress.ProgressReportService|Information|0|Fetching valid and locally installed signing identities...
> Xamarin.VisualStudio.Progress.ProgressReportService|Information|0|Syncing certificates for "Ivan" team...
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic xvs/idb/auto-provision-output
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - An application message for topic xvs/idb/auto-provision-output was received
> Xamarin.VisualStudio.Progress.ProgressReportService|Information|0|Creating certificate signing request for Ivan...
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic xma/ping/vs12345IVAN
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - An application message for topic xma/ping/vs12345IVAN was received
> Xamarin.Messaging.Client.PingHandler|Information|0|vs12345IVAN received ping. Sending acknowledge...
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic xvs/idb/auto-provision-output
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - An application message for topic xvs/idb/auto-provision-output was received
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - Dispatching PublishAck message to flow PublishSenderFlow
> Xamarin.VisualStudio.Progress.ProgressReportService|Information|0|Creating certificate...
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic vs12345IVAN/response/xma/ping/Broker169000292
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - An application message for topic vs12345IVAN/response/xma/ping/Broker169000292 was received
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic xvs/idb/auto-provision-output
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - An application message for topic xvs/idb/auto-provision-output was received
> Xamarin.VisualStudio.Progress.ProgressReportService|Information|0|There was an error while trying to automatically provision the project, please check the logs.
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic vs12345IVAN/error/xvs/idb/auto-provision
> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs12345IVAN - An application message for topic vs12345IVAN/error/xvs/idb/auto-provision was received
> Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient|Error|0|An error occurred on the receiver while executing a post for topic xvs/idb/auto-provision and client vs12345IVAN
> Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client IDBLocal123456789 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/auto-provision ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.
> at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.DeveloperPortalWebClient.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<b__2>d.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/DeveloperPortalWebClient.cs:line 127
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.DeveloperPortalWebClient.d__25.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/DeveloperPortalWebClient.cs:line 125
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AuthorizedDeveloperPortalClient.d__7.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AuthorizedDeveloperPortalClient.cs:line 100
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AuthorizedDeveloperPortalClient.d__4.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AuthorizedDeveloperPortalClient.cs:line 48
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AppleDeveloperPortal.d__24.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AppleDeveloperPortal.cs:line 215
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.CreateCertificate.d__9.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/ProvisioningTasks/CreateCertificate.cs:line 84
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.ResolveCertificate.d__13.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/ProvisioningTasks/ResolveCertificate.cs:line 90
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.d__20.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\1\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line 369
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.AutoProvisionHandler.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\1\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\Handlers\AutoProvisionHandler.cs:line 17
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2.<HandleAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Handlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager.<>c__DisplayClass16_1`2.<b__2>d.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessageHandlerManager.cs:line 0
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.d__32`2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 0 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.ApplicationMessageExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__1(MqttApplicationMessage m) in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Extensions\ApplicationMessageExtensions.cs:line 194
> at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2.Selector._.OnNext(TSource value) in d:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Linq\Observable\Select.cs:line 39 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 190

Comment: [Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.9.6) was just released. It fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio have a new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ7J2.png)

**Just update the Visual Studio**